# No known conversion for argument 1 from 'Object*' to 'int*'

Tags: c++, pointer

I'm terrible with pointers and need help passing an object to a library I'm writing. I'm getting the error `no known conversion for argument 1 from 'LCDMenuItem*' to 'int*'` when I try to compile. How do I pass a pointer to an object to a function?

*LCDMenu.h*

```
class LCDMenu {
    public:
    bool addItem(LCDMenuItem &item);
    private:
    LCDMenuItem *menuItems[MAX_ITEMS];
    uint8_t itemCount;
};

class LCDMenuItem {
    public:
    LCDMenuItem(char *name);
    bool setFunction(void (*function)(void));
    private:
    bool callFunction() const;
    void (*_function)(void);
    char *name;
};
```

*LCDMenu.cpp*

```
bool LCDMenu::addItem(LCDMenuItem &item) {
    menuItems[itemCount] = &item;
    ...
}
```

*MySketch.ino*

```
LCDMenuItem menuItem("Menu Option");
void setup() {
    menu.addItem(menuItem);
}
```

*When trying to compile*

> ```
> bool addItem(LCDMenuItem *item);
>      ^
> ```
>
> no known conversion for argument 1 from 'LCDMenuItem*' to 'int*'

Comment: what is `menuItem` and where is `bool addItem(LCDMenuItem *item);`?

Comment: Edited. Do you mean `menuItems`? its an array of `LCDMenuItem`'s addItem() is in LCDMenu.cpp

Comment: `menu.addItem(menuItem);` menuItem. do you have the classes in that order in .h file?

Comment: Oh, sorry. added that to MySketch.ino. I just reordered the classes putting LCDMenuItem first, didn't help.

Comment: and `bool addItem(LCDMenuItem *item);` reported by compiler is where?

Comment: i dont have one :) doesnt `bool addItem(LCDMenuItem &item)` let you pass the object like im trying to do? (obviously not)

Comment: it does. it is passing by reference and it is ok. something else is wrong.

Comment: do you have some other function called addItem in your sketch?

Comment: I don't think so. But i just got it to compile in a new sketch so now I'll track down what is causing that.